# How to call factory methods from HTML in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

In `controller` I have followed methods:

```
var isPaused  = false; 

$scope.switcher = function (booleanExpr, trueValue, falseValue) {
    return booleanExpr ? trueValue : falseValue;
};

$scope.isPaused = function () {
    return isPaused;
};
```

And I can call it from HTML like:

```
<body  ng-controller="Cntrl">

...
<h4>
 {{ switcher( isPaused(), 'Search Address Mode', 'Search Location Mode' )}}
</h4>
 <div class="btn-group">
    ...     
 </div>
```

As you see if `isPaused()` returns `false` I get `<h4>Search Location Mode</h4>`

This is utility therefore I want to define it as `factory`

```
feederliteModule.factory('switcher', function () {   
return {
    sw: function (booleanExpr, trueValue, falseValue) {
        return booleanExpr ? trueValue : falseValue;  
    }
  };
});
```

No exceptions but

when I try to call it like:

```
<h4>
 {{ switcher.sw( isPaused(), 'Search Address Mode', 'Search Location Mode' )}}
</h4>
 <div class="btn-group">
    ...     
 </div>
```

Nothing happens.

**I added `'switcher'` to controller.

How can I call factory method from HTML?

(*You welcome to change/edit my question if it seems not clear)

Thank you,

Comment: how did you manage to accomplish this?I have a similar problem … might be I just shouldn't be doing all this like that

Comment: @user1524316   well, see answer  below

Comment: I thought it did not solve your question entirely since its not accepted?

Comment: couse I know you can call it like he showed below. But I need to be able to call it with ng-click … so I just need to leave my method in controller and not in a separate factory?

Comment: @user1524316 yep, it was some gap, accepted

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Well, you're not really supposed to do that... but what you *can* do is put your service object in a property on your $scope, and call it from there.

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, switcher) {
   $scope.switcher = switcher;
});
```

Comment: Why not supposed? is it seems messy?. Your solution works. THe question is why I need create `$scope.switcher` if `controller` receives `switcher` identifier. Thanks

Comment: HTML views can only be linked to Controller (using the $scope variable) or extended with Directives. Any other way is not an angular way :)

Comment: @Chandermani I use this method in several controllers and the easy/short way is to create factory or service.

Comment: Because when you add {{}} expressions, angular calls $scope.$eval() and $scope.$eval looks at things differently, it seems MyVariable as $scope.MyVariable, if you try {{switcher}} it will just look for $scope.switcher.

Answer (score 3):

I had a more general question, "How to call angularjs scope/factory/service from html on page load."  My solution was to call the method within ng-show.

1. At the highest element surrounding the context in question,
2. Call the method using the ng-show directive.
3. The method will run prior to displaying the page.
4. Note you can also use a solution like this to make sure that bootstrapping work is finished prior to displaying a page (this can reduce the number of moving parts in a scattered rendering)

> `<div ng-show="runThisMethod(someVarOnScope)" .....>`

Answer (score 0):

Using ***AngularJS 1.7.2*** and Page Controller (Every Webpage has it's own controller)

First take the ***Factory*** view:

```
AppName.factory('eventMate', function() {
    let obj = this;

    obj.search = "";

    obj.setSearchValue = function(value) {
        obj.search = value;
        return obj.search;
    };

    obj.getSearchValue = function() {
        return obj.search;
    };

    return obj;
});
```

In one of the child Controller, named **`rfcController`**

```
AppName.controller("rfcController", function ($scope, $http, $filter, $window, $location, $anchorScroll,
                                               textMate, datetimeMate, restpack, pagination, imageMate, eventMate) {

    //there are many more service providers and injectors also, just showing for an idea
    $scope.eventMate = eventMate;


    $scope.getFiltered = function(){
        let searchValue = $scope.eventMate.getSearchValue().toString();

        if(searchValue === undefined){
            return "";
        } else {
            return searchValue.toString();
        }
    };
}
```

Now see the source through html side, where I will call this method.

```
<table>
    <tr class="rfc_table_td_tr" ng-repeat="(key, value) in rfcDetails | filter:getFiltered()">
        <td>{{value.createdDate}}</td>
        <td>{{value.rfcTitle}}</td>
        <td>{{value.rfcDetails}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Hope it will help many one. **:D**