# ionic side menu not getting refreshed

Tags: angularjs, menu, refresh, ionic-framework

i have ionic side menu > and it has sign-up and sign-in links.
i am trying to hide the sign-up and sign-in based on the logged in state.

if logged in then sign-in, sign-up links should be hidden and if not logged in then both should be visible.

i am using angular factory to save the sate and using ng-show/ng-hide attributes trying to do the toggling. but it's not working.

please help.

regards,
ad

below is my code:
html:
        
          
          Sign-In

```
    <ion-item menu-close class="item-icon-left" ng-click="signup()" ng-show ="AppGlobalValues.isLoggedIn()" >
             <i class="icon ion-edit"></i>
      Sign-Up
    </ion-item>
```

### services.js

.......
.factory('AppGlobalValues', function() {
  // Might use a resource here that returns a JSON array

// Some fake testing data
  //

var loggedIn = 'FALSE';

return {

```
init:function(){
  loggedIn = 'FALSE';

},

setLoggedIn: function(pLoggedIn) {
    loggedIn=pLoggedIn;
},

isLoggedIn: function(num){

  console.log("number:",num);

    return loggedIn;


}
```

};
})

Answer (score 0):

The service needs to be made available on the controller to be allowed access it.

see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16545530/how-to-call-factory-methods-from-html-in-angularjs)

If you really want to access your services on a global level, you could attach them to the $rootScope and use them from there.

Comment: sorry but i read that $rootScope is not a good practice and everywhere i found to use service. it's working in normal page but in the side menu it's not. i am injecting the service to the controller. it's available there. in fact i checked the console, each time i click the side menu button (appearing at top left corner), it calls the function which is in ng-hide and it shows right value but that value has no affect on the menu item (sign-in and sign-up).

Answer (score 0):

there was an initialization issue in services. that was messing up the toggling. i removed initialization and now it works perfect.

thanks for the help.